# How to import vector images into image assets in xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, vector, xcode8, vector-graphics

I read this tutorial for importing vector images into xcode:
[How to Use Vectors in Xcode 7](https://icons8.com/articles/how-to-use-vectors-in-xcode-7/)

But it seams it is different in xcode 8.

I created an image set in XCAsset file, however, in xcode 8, there is not "Scale Factors" attribute in its Attribute Inspector.

Where is it?
How can I import vector images into image assets in xcode 8?

Answer (score 16):

In Xcode 8 "Scale Factors" was renamed to "Scales".

[image: XCode 8 Vectors]

Comment: This seems to replace the "Types - Vectors" selector in previous versions of Xcode, as seen in guides like: http://martiancraft.com/blog/2014/09/vector-images-xcode6/